# Access violation with strcpy in c

Tags: c, exception, char, c-strings, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_OF_RECORD 100


void main()
{
   char lineBuffer[SIZE_OF_RECORD];
   memset(lineBuffer, '\0', (SIZE_OF_RECORD - 1) * sizeof(char));


   strcpy(lineBuffer, "testing"); strcat(lineBuffer, ',');  //exception thrown here Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCB7B5D1CB (ucrtbased.dll) in PA_2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000002C.
   printf("line buffer after assemble line \n%s", lineBuffer);
    
}
```

I do not understand. The string as it is declared should not be read only right? Why cant I change it?

Comment: Compiler warnings can help you avoid issues like these. https://godbolt.org/z/csfKGWaza

Comment: Besides the obvious warning tat your compiler should throw at you, avoid the use of `strcpy` and `strcat`. Usually `snprintf` does a better job, but if you must, use `strncpy` and `strncat`. In either case, pass the size of the buffer.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` to reduce the changes of having a buffer overflow attack to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strcat` expects two arguments of the type char * but you are calling it passing an object of the type int

```
strcat(lineBuffer, ',');
```

The function `strcat` is declared like

```
char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

At least write

```
strcat(lineBuffer, ",");
```

using the string literal `","` instead of the integer character constant.

Also it is unclear why in this call

```
memset(lineBuffer, '\0', (SIZE_OF_RECORD - 1) * sizeof(char));
```

you are using the expression (SIZE_OF_RECORD - 1) instead of SIZE_OF_RECORD. You could write

```
memset(lineBuffer, '\0', sizeof(lineBuffer ));
```

Comment: Or just drop the `memset` entirely and declare it with `char lineBuffer[SIZE_OF_RECORD] = {0};`

Comment: Those double quotes. Thank you, that made my day. As for memset I assumed it was good practice to explicitly define the size of the type. But idk, Im very new to this.

Comment: @JacobSmith sizeof(lineBuffer ) is the size of the declared array type.